# PHP - JSON_ENCODE - Remove quotes from value

Tags: php

I am using json_encode to display some data.

```
[{"name":"myname001","data":["[Date.UTC(1961, 1, 1),10]","[Date.UTC(1962, 1, 1),11]"},{"name":"myname002", "data":["[Date.UTC(1961, 1, 1),10]","[Date.UTC(1962, 1, 1),11]" ]]
```

How can I remove the double quotes from the values from my data?

```
[{"name":"myname001","data":[[Date.UTC(1961, 1, 1),10],[Date.UTC(1962, 1, 1),11]},{"name":"myname002", "data":[[Date.UTC(1961, 1, 1),10],[Date.UTC(1962, 1, 1),11] ]]
```

Comment: Removing quotes from values would make your JSON invalid.

Comment: Yes, but I need to remove it. Some idea?

Comment: I want to see why the HighStock need to read the JSON without the double quotes. Because this I need a way to remove it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, I know. But after my json_encode the HighStock won't work with double quotes, I need to check why, because this my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, so easy.

The situation: I need to bring number to put together with highstock, and was not bringing anything.

After I just did a new array with int numbers, this way is coming without double quotes.

I don't know why people give negative without ask why the question.

Closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK option.

```
<?php
$arr = array( 'row_id' => '1', 'name' => 'George' ); // fictional db result
echo json_encode( $arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ); // {"row_id":1,"name":"George"}
?>
```

Comment: seems JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK also change a year that is between double qoutes, e.g. "2016".